# Algebra is noetherian if associated graded algebra is noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian, algebras, filtrations, graded-algebras

$
\newcommand{\cn}{\colon}
\newcommand{\<}{\leqslant}
\newcommand{\>}{\geqslant}
\newcommand{\ss}{\subset}
\newcommand{\gr}{\mathrm{gr}}
$
Let $A$ be associative commutative algebra with unity and filtration $0=F_{-1}\ss F_0\ss F_1\ss\ldots\ss A=\bigcup_i F_i$, $1\in F_0$, $\gr(A)=\bigoplus_{i\>0} F_i/F_{i-1}$ be noetherian associated graded algebra. I want to prove that $A$ is also noetherian (exercise 4 after chapter 1 from **Kassel's Quantum Groups**).

Let $A_i=F_i/F_{i-1}$. I see that $A_i$ and $B_j=\gr(A)/\left(\bigoplus_{i\>j}A_i\right)$ are noetherian but how it can be seen that $A$ is finitely generated over $A_i$ or $B_j$? Or maybe exists some epimorphism $\gr(A)\to A$ or $B_j\to A$ for some $j$? Can it help if $\gr(A)$ and $A$ are integral domains?

Comment: This is proved in *Noncommutative Noetherian Rings* by McConnell, Robson, Small, sections 1.6 and 1.7. I'm afraid I don't have my copy to hand though so I can't tell you how it goes.